# Web hooks in Python: Any particular library?

Tags: python, webhooks

I wanted to implement web hooks in python. Both at server end and client end.  Is there any particular library for implementing web hooks? Or does django or twisted python handle this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "web hooks"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should probably mention that "web hooks" is a specific concept -- as explained at [webhooks.org](http://webhooks.org/) -- to avoid getting generic answers about the web, as I see you already have.  It's hardly a popular or widespread concept, so the answerers' utter confusion is not surprising but easily predictable.

On your question, I know of [Hookah](http://blog.webhooks.org/2009/03/02/announcing-hookah-the-web-hook-event-dispatcher/) (from the webhooks.org site) and [durian](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/durian/0.1.0) (web hooks for Django).  There are specific ones, such as [TracWebHooks](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/TracWebHooks/0.0.1) for adding web hooks to the issue tracking service Trac, but I gather you're looking for something more general.

Comment: My apologies .. I should have clarified the term Webhooks as given by you.  I just peeked into the sites for Hookah and Durian.  Both seem to be in alpha stage, but it seems that Hookah is aiming to be more comprehensive.  So it seems, Hookah might be the answer for me. Thanks.